# ValueError: time data '2018-02-22' does not match format '%m-%d-%Y' when using https://stocknewsapi.com/

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, api

I have a bunch of daily data in ohlc format:

```
       index        date symbol    open    high   low  close     volume       vwap  previous_close  change_1_day
0       7896  2018-02-22    CHK   2.870   3.330  2.86   3.20  130538189   3.109534          2.6300     21.673004
1       8108  2018-12-26    CHK   1.950   2.190  1.85   2.19   80610326   2.015611          1.7300     26.589595
2      27084  2020-06-12   CHNR   4.805   6.040  1.37   1.47   47780632   3.797993          0.9540     54.088050
3      27235  2021-01-19   CHNR   2.260   3.090  2.18   2.33   23674990   2.588788          1.7200     35.465116
4      57521  2020-06-04   CIDM   4.380   6.000  3.15   3.63  223314246   3.994496          1.3100    177.099237
..       ...         ...    ...     ...     ...   ...    ...        ...        ...             ...           ...
909  9471547  2018-09-24   AMRN  10.440  12.470  9.51  12.40  163106698  10.848351          2.9900    314.715719
910  9481473  2020-10-12   WIMI   5.330   8.199  5.30   7.06   66982871   7.203527          5.2800     33.712121
911  9545909  2022-09-29   SNTI   1.640   2.410  1.63   2.11   74311098   2.028829          1.4000     50.714286
912  9664240  2019-10-31   AGRX   1.500   1.540  1.03   1.20   60075942   1.352889          0.3706    223.799244
913  9664242  2019-11-04   AGRX   1.500   1.890  1.45   1.78   29016013   1.728473          1.3500     31.851852

[914 rows x 11 columns]
```

I am trying to loop over my data to add a column when there is news for that day:

```
for row in df.iterrows():
    # get the date
    date = row[1][1]
    # get the symbol
    symbol = row[1][2]
    # end date
    end_date =  datetime.strptime(date, '%m-%d-%Y').date()
    # start date is minus one business day
    start_date = (end_date - BDay(1)).date()

    print(start_date, 'start_date')
    print(end_date, 'end date')

    print(type(start_date))
    print(type(end_date))
    
    # turn into unix
    unixend = mktime(start_date.timetuple())
    unixstart = mktime(end_date.timetuple())
    print(unixend, 'unixend')
    print(unixstart, 'unixstart')

    url = f'https://stocknewsapi.com/api/v1?tickers={symbol}&items=3&page=1&date={unixstart-unixend}&token=4q4cwm1jys26wovaedhmy01x7ysxfnkpzjpmyysp'
    response = requests.get(url)
    print(response)
```

Which gives the error:

```
    raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
ValueError: time data '2018-02-22' does not match format '%m-%d-%Y'
```

The [documentation](https://stocknewsapi.com/documentation) says:

> Use the date parameters to obtain historical news (up to March 2019).
> Please use the following format: MMDDYYYY. You can also use: last5min,
> last10min, last15min, last30min, last45min, last60min, today,
> yesterday, last7days, last30days, last60days, last90days, yeartodate.

And gives example of data parameter in unix:

```
&date=03152019-03252019
```

The output from my print statements:

```
<class 'datetime.date'>
<class 'datetime.date'>
1572588000.0 unixend
1572847200.0 unixstart
```

**Desired result**: I want to get the news for each day in my business column, starting from 1 business day before.

What am I getting wrong here?

Comment: The format of the date you pass to the api does not seem to match the format of the date you get back from the api

Comment: Yeah, I asked openai and it said the same thing. I am now looking how to make it unix date and not timestamp. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The documentation specifies the input date format for the API.

Your dataframe does not have it in this format.

```
end_date =  datetime.strptime(date, '%m-%d-%Y').date()
```

While your dates are like this: 2018-02-22

```
end_date = datetime.strptime(date,'%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%m%d%Y')
```